# wtfform validation stops working when html form action set to return following page

Tags: python, html, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I've set up DataRequired validation in two wtform components which comprise a SelectField and a StringField.

The information input by the user on the `index` page is then intended to carry into the following `results` page.

The validation works when the `form action` attribute in the `index.html` file is set to `""`. However, the inputted form data is not stored in a variable and carried to the `results` in this scenario (the table field on the results page show "None").

However, when the `form action` attribute in `index.html` is set to `results` the inputed field data Is stored and carried over to the results page, but DataRequired validation no longer takes place, presumably because the html action attribute bypasses the `if form.validate_on_submit()` in the `views.py` file.

Here are the `index.html`,`forms.py` and `views.py` files for reference. How can I find a way for the validation to work AND the inputted data to carry over to the results page?

views.py file:

```
####Index Page
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
        exception = ""
        try:
            connectToDB()
        except:
            exception = 'Failure to connect to db'
        form = StaffNames()
        if not exception:
                if form.validate_on_submit():
                        return redirect('/results')
        return render_template('index.html',title='Search Page',exception=exception,form=form)

#####Results Page
@app.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
        form =StaffNames()
        return render_template('results.html',
                           title='Results', form=form, staff_name = dict(staff_choices).get(form.staff.data))
```

index.html:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="index">
        <p> {{ form.hidden_tag() }} </p>
        <p>{{ form.ranumber }} Enter RA Number</p>
        {% for error in form.ranumber.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
          {% endfor %}<br>
        <p>{{ form.staff }} Select your name</p>
        {% for error in form.staff.errors %}
         <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
          {% endfor %}<br>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Search"></p>
    </form>
```

forms.py:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


staff_choices=[("", ""), ('1', 'John Jones'), ('2', 'Chris Hughes'), ('            3', 'Lyn Tony')]
class StaffNames(Form):
        ranumber = StringField('ranumber', validators=[DataRequired()])
        staff = SelectField('staff',choices=staff_choices,validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to pass the form data as query string?

```
####Index Page
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
        exception = ""
        try:
            connectToDB()
        except:
            exception = 'Failure to connect to db'

        form = StaffNames()
        if not exception:
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                query = {
                    'staff': form.staff.data,
                    'ranumber': form.ranumber.data
                }
                return redirect(url_for('results', **query))

        return render_template(
            'index.html', title='Search Page', exception=exception, form=form
        )


#####Results Page
from flask import request

@app.route('/results')
def results():
    ranumber = request.args.get('ranumber', None)
    staff = request.args.get('staff', None)

    return render_template(
        'results.html', title='Results', staff=staff, ranumber=ranumber
    )
```

This way you can skip form's action attribute altogether

```
<form method="post" name="index">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, this has worked thanks- can you just explain the `**query` bit, what does the `**` do? Cheers

Comment: @nmh **query is the same as **kwargs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python; and here is how url_for uses it: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for